# Web Scraping Javascript Table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to web scraping and prototyping using various websites. I am having difficulties with scraping what seems to be Javascript loaded tables. Any help would be much appreciated. The following is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url='https://onlineservice.cvo.org/webs/cvo/register/#/search/
toronto/0/1/0/10'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all(class_='table')
print(tables)
```

Comment: That table is loaded with js, so you first need a client that's able to run the js on that page and then parse the result...I believe selenium is the recommended tool for doing that. But you can also check this tutorial and see if it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any other alternative to pyQT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below url to get all the information with the blink of an eye. You can retrieve that url by using chrome dev tools at xhr request under network tab. Give it a shot:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://onlineservice.cvo.org/rest/public/registrant/search/?query=%20toronto&status=0&type=1&skip=0&take=427'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get(URL,headers=headers,verify=False)

for items in response.json()['result']:
    lastname = items['lastName']
    firstname = items['firstName']
    commonname = items['commonName']
    status = items['registrationStatus']['name']
    print(lastname,firstname,commonname,status)
```

Partial results:

```
Aadoson Andres Andres Active
Aarabi Alireza Allen Active
Aarnes Turi Turi Expired
Abbasi Tashfeen Tashfeen Active
Abbott Jonathan Jonathan Resigned
Abd El Nour Emad Emad Active
Abdel Hady Medhat Hady Active
Abdelhalim Khaled Khaled Active
```

Comment: I am at the Network tab and I clicked on the xhr request but I can't find the url

Comment: Go through [this site](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/chrome-devtools-network-tab-tricks/) to understand how it works.